# Find smallest enclosed area of a grid

Tags: arrays, math, matrix, discrete-mathematics

There is a grid, the edges of which are always wall.

The internal area of the grid is also divided by walls into several sub-areas, like this

1 = Wall,
0 = Empty.

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

I need to find the smallest empty sub-area.
How do i do it?

Comment: This can be solved with a flood-fill algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Telescope's suggestion is correct. Here's a slightly more detailed illustration of how you might approach this.

Given an M x N grid, you will loop over the (M - 2)(N - 2) subgrid ignoring the outer walls. When looking at a given grid cell:

- if the grid cell is 0, you have not seen this area yet; begin a flood fill here that counts the number of adjacent 0s and changes them to 2 to mark them as having been seen already in some enclosed area, to avoid having to re-flood this area again later
- if a grid cell is 1, it's an interior wall and should be skipped
- if the grid cell is 2, you have seen this area already and can skip it

At the end, you'll have counted the area of each distinct enclosed section and can choose the biggest, smallest, or whichever you need to know.

This algorithm will visit each cell at most a few times (worst case is a 1 surrounded by 0s which the flood fill will bump into up to four times, and the wall will be checked once during the subgrid scan). Therefore, the time complexity is O(MN). The algorithm uses the grid itself to keep track of what it has done so far, so no extra memory is used; if the grid must not be modified in place, an extra O(MN) memory can be allocated for a working copy.